# Pull out information from api

Tags: javascript

What is the code (in javascript) in order to loop through the whole api and pull out the coordinates/address so I will be able to map it?

Here is a basic example of me fetching the api:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

    fetch('url').then(function (response) {
       // The API call was successful!
       return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
       // This is the JSON from our response
       console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
       // There was an error
       console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest starting with a basic javascript tutorial

Comment: To get started => [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Add this inside your **.then** => `data.forEach(function(x){console.log("Lat: "+ x.latitude +" Long "+x.longitude+" : "+x.address);` to get the data you need!!

Answer (score 1):

The script below can help you.

Example (open up the console): https://jsfiddle.net/4pv591wg/

```
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    fetch('url').then(function (response) {
       // The API call was successful!
       return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        
        console.log(`${item.agency} --- Lat: ${item.latitude} --- Long: ${item.longitude}`);
      
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {
       // There was an error
       console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
```